# How to select the rows with highest values in sequence in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose that I have a table with the following data:

```
id  |  Value
_ _ _ _ _ _ _
1      0
2      1
3      2
4      0
5      1
6      0 
7      1
8      2
9      3
10     4
```

And I want to select only those rows that get to a maximum, sort by the id.
The result rows would be:

```
3     2
5     1
10    4
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to do something like

```
SELECT id, 
       value
  FROM (SELECT id,
               value,
               lead(value) over (order by id) next_value
          FROM your_table)
 WHERE next_value < value
    OR next_value IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, value 
from (
  select id, value, lead(value, 1, 0)over(order by id) as next from table
) 
where next = 0 
order by id
```